# Where are Laravel 5.1 Repositories?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was going through socialite tutorial which is created by Laravel 5 and I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I saw that there is a file in tutorial like `AuthenticateUser.php` in repositories folder. But repositories folder doesn't even exist in Laravel 5.1. Where I should create a file `AuthenticateUser.php` in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: 5.1 removed the basic auth functionality that was in 5.0, that may have something to do with it - see the upgrade notes: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses composer's autoloading, so it doesn't matter where you store your files, so long as their autoloading mechanism is defined in the `composer.json` file. Laravel 5 apps start with this defined in their `composer.json`:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}
```

So if you created a directory at `app/Repositories`, you could create a file in it that looked like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories;

class MyRepository {

    public function doSomething() {}

}
```

Then you can reference it in the rest of your application like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\MyRepository;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

FooController {

    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(MyRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        return $this->repo->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Composer will load the file for you, so long as you've defined a mechanism for doing so.